# How to collect eigenvectors corresponding to only real eigenvalues?

Tags: matrix

I have a set of eigenvalues which consists of real and imaginary values. Among these, I have one purely positive real eigenvalue and one purely negative real eigenvalue. How do I collect these two eigenvalues' corresponding eigenvectors?

Thanks

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182612/how-to-collect-eigenvectors-corresponding-to-only-positive-eigenvalues, but you just need `Thread[Im[vals] == 0]` instead of `Positive[vals]`.

Comment: Maybe ``{eigenvalues, eigenvectors} = Eigensystem[A];
Pick[eigenvectors, Developer`RealQ/@eigenvalues]``?

Answer (score 3):

```
eigenvalues = Eigenvalues[A];
eigenvaluesReal = Select[eigenvalues, Im[#]==0&];
```

where `A` is your matrix (or equivalently, `eigenvalues` is your list)

**Edit:** OP wanted eigenvectors, not eigenvalues.

```
eigenvectors = Eigenvectors[A]
eigenvectorsReal = Pick[eigenvectors, Map[Im[#] == 0 &, eigenvalues]]
```

Comment: The OP wanted the eigenvectors not eigenvalues

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks for the remark, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 4}]
Select[ Transpose[Eigensystem[A]], Im[#[[1]]] == 0 &] // Chop
```

which gives you pairs `{eigenvalue, eigenvector}` for real eigenvalues!

Answer (score 1):

When you want to pick elements from one list according to criteria in another list, the function we use is [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html). When designing the spec, then, we want to be efficient and use vectorized operations. Here we just want to `Pick` the eigenvectors with `Im[λ]==0.` so we do:

```
A = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[0]; RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 1000}]];
{eigenvalues, eigenvectors} = Eigensystem[A];

Pick[eigenvectors, Unitize@Im@eigenvalues, 0] // Length

28
```

(I use [`Unitize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unitize.html) here simply because `Pick` performs better with it and `0`)

On the other hand, say you wanted those with non-zero imaginary part, here we can't just use `0.`, but that's okay because we can use `Unitize` to turn all non-zero components into `1`:

```
Pick[eigenvectors, Unitize[Im@eigenvalues], 1] // Length

972
```

Or you can pull those within a region of zero, say `1` (the `UnitStep` windowing trick is very useful and can be used in many, many places):

```
Pick[
  eigenvectors,
  UnitStep[1 - #] - UnitStep[1 + #] &@Im@eigenvalues,
  0
  ] // Length

76
```