# Predicting Pick performance

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I'm trying to figure out how to use `Pick` most efficiently. I use it already in a number of places, but only ever in the context of `UnitStep` and `0` selector specs. When working on [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/188466/38205) though I hit some odd performance results, though. Here's the setup:

```
A = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[0]; RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 1000}]];
{eigenvalues, eigenvectors} = Eigensystem[A];
```

And now say I want to pick the eigenvectors corresponding to real eigenvalues, here's what I thought to do:

```
Pick[eigenvectors, Im@eigenvalues, 0.]; // RepeatedTiming

{0.15, Null}
```

This is bizarre. That's terrible performance for `Pick`. So then check out this:

```
Pick[eigenvectors, Unitize@Im@eigenvalues, 0]; // RepeatedTiming

{0.000047, Null}
```

That's much more in line with expectation.

Okay, then, let's try picking for non-real eigenvalues:

```
Pick[eigenvectors, Unitize@Im@eigenvalues, 1]; // RepeatedTiming

{0.0047, Null}
```

Much, much slower, but this could simply be because we're returning a much larger set of results, requiring more memory to be copied. I could believe it.

Now, just for fun I wanted to see what happens if I numericize everything:

```
Pick[eigenvectors, N@Unitize@Im@eigenvalues, 0.]; // RepeatedTiming

{0.15, Null}

Pick[eigenvectors, N@Unitize@Im@eigenvalues, 1.]; // RepeatedTiming

{0.0061, Null}
```

All of a sudden the performance has flipped (and quite dramatically). We're back to the original performance for the `0.` case, but not for the `1.` case. There we have almost the same performance as before. So then I thought that `0.` might be special, so I decided to try a no-zero case in the original setup:

```
Im@eigenvalues // First

17.491604555909646

Pick[eigenvectors, Im@eigenvalues, 
   17.491604555909646]; // RepeatedTiming

{0.15, Null}
```

And so that's clearly not what's going on...so what is? What explains these wildly divergent performance characteristics of `Pick` (and how can I use this to make sure I'm always doing things most efficiently)

Comment: Hint: `Pick[wrap /@ eigenvectors, Im@eigenvalues, 0.]; // RepeatedTiming` is 10x faster.  I believe this may have to do with the fact that `Pick` does not only operate at level 1, and may scan all elements of the first argument (even though the second one clearly indicates that level 1 is sufficient).